# cordova android: Reduce the available localizations to the supported app languages

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, internationalization, cordova-android

For iOS its simple; There is a plist setting. For `cordova ios` platform just use for example:

```
<edit-config target="CFBundleLocalizations" file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite">
   <array>
       <string>de</string>
       <string>en</string>
   </array>
</edit-config>
```

How to archive the same for android platform?

Comment: Check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android